# It's possible to create App Service Plans using Azure Powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

As the title say, I need to create App Service Plans programmatilly, The scenario:

- N azure websites will be created (dynamically, using azure powershell too)
- If someday the Premium App Service Plan can't handle the quantity of websites (even with autoscaling by cpu usage), another service plan must be created to hold new sites.

It is possible? Or Am I going to the wrong way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your design doesn't permit it, when you create a new Premium App Service Plan, create it in a new resource group, as that will give it a greater chance to have enough capacity to scale.

Using Azure PowerShell version 1.1.0 you can use the following command to create new app service plans

`New-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Location "South Central US" -ResourceGroupName DestinationAzureResourceGroup -Name NewAppServicePlan -Sku Premium`