# Setting Azure Function app settings using Powershell Set-AzureRmWebApp function fails with Bad Request error

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, devops

I want to set an existing Azure function's app settings from Powershell. I have the following script

```
$FunctionSettings = @{     
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING" = "*******";    
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE" = "TestFunction123";
    "AzureWebJobsStorage" = "*******";    
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION" = "~2";
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = "dotnet";       
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" = "10.14.1";    
}

Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "RGN" -AppSettings $FunctionSettings -Name "TestFunction"
```

Running this script returns this error

> Set-AzureRmWebApp : Operation returned an invalid status code
>   'BadRequest'
>       At C:\Users******\Source\Repos*******\Create Azure infrastructure.ps1:101 char:1
>       + Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $AzureResourceGroupName -AppSett ...
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmWebApp], DefaultErrorResponseException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Cmdlets.WebApps.SetAzureWebAppCmdlet

If I remove the WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE from $FunctionSettings then the script runs successfully but I get errors in the Azure UI because those properties are required.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does your storage account support Blob, Queue, Table, and File storage? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637581/create-a-consumption-based-app-service-plan-with-powershell

Comment: @MarieHoeger Thanks, I've checked that and it does support those. In fact if I create a new function through the web interface and select the same storage account, it works.

Comment: Your comment means you create a new function and the script works fine? If not, could you try to use the Az command `Set-AzWebApp`? I tried it with a consumption function app, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know 1 year has passed and you probably solved your problem but today while I was creating a PS script I encountered the same problem. On my case the order of the settings did the trick. Put the WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE first on your hastable.

```
    $AzFunctionAppSettings = @{}
    $AzFunctionAppSettings = @{
        APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = $AppInsightsKey
        APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING = $AppInsightsConString
        FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~1"
        FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = "dotnet"
        WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE = "****"
        WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING = "***"
    }
```